# FTP mdelete, 550 No Such Directory error - BATCH SCRIPT

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am trying to delete some text files in a FTP Path with a batch script. The files are getting deleted but there is an error in the CMD Window that - `550 NO SUCH DIRECTORY`.

I stored the below commands in a `DISCH.BAT` file

```
 open XXXXXXXXX.net
 USERNAME
 PASSWORD    
 cd METS
 cd MARVELTSHIP
 binary
 mdelete *.txt
 quit
```

And I am executing the above `DISCH.BAT` through `RUN.BAT` as below

```
 ftp -i -s:C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\DISCH.bat
 pause
```

And I can see the command Prompt window as below...

[image: 550 ERROR]

How to avoid this `550 No such Directory` error. Can you please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What makes you believe that's a `METS` directory at all? Show us some proof.

Comment: Hi Martin... I can actually see the METS folder when I open the FTP Domain ***.NET. So, can this be a directory..??

Comment: *"I open the FTP Domain ***.NET."* - What does this mean? Do you mean that you open something like `http://www.xxxx.net/METS/MARVELTSHIP/` in web browser?

Comment: Can you please look at these - [PIC 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Q64fahdsDpRzdVSG9ndWdjVTQ) , [PIC 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Q64fahdsDpSFlGd2xRTl9fa1k).

Comment: could you do `ftp://www.xxxx.net/METS/` then?

Comment: `cd METS` --> `cd /METS`?

Comment: After you login with `ftp.exe` and type `pwd`, what does it say? If you type `ls`, what listing do you get? Does it show the `METS`?

Answer (score 0):

Well from the log it appears that the directory `METS` does not exist or you don't have access to it, thus you can not change to it.  Then you are changing to `MARVELTSHIP` to which you have access and you change to it and delete the files there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With the Username and password, I was able to access the METS Folder. I can even place the files, delete the files in `METS` itself instead of `MARVELTSHIP`. But mysteriously its throwing the above error. Any idea how to get rid of this..?? Thank you.

Comment: @METALHEAD: What if you change the line in the script to "/METS" (if it is in to ftp root) or adjust it to the path.

Comment: I've tried with `/METS` . Still getting the same. We cannot place the full path in the beginning `OPEN` Statement as `XXXX.net/METS/MARVELTSHIP`. Its a syntax error. The `cd` commands can be placed after the credentials. FIles are getting moved/Deleted. No issues with that. Its just the error that's irritating. Thank you.

Comment: @METALHEAD: could you do it manually and update your question with that screenshot?